# MKL sparse matrix product makes no sense

Tags: python, ctypes, intel-mkl

I have composed the following code from pieces that I've found searching on the internet.

So far the code runs, but the results make no sense.

I have three questions:

a) How am I supposed to compose the output matrix C, if only the matrix data is returned by reference?

b) Why does the data not resemble the results from scipy (which are correct)

c) Why is the MKL code so much slower?

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix, random, diags
from ctypes import *

mkl = cdll.LoadLibrary("libmkl_rt.so")


def sparse_csc_mm(A, B):
    # from: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/TpuMdSVSf4E
    # A must be in CSC format, could enforce here with a check

    m = A.shape[0]
    n = A.shape[1]
    Bn = B.shape[1]

    Ax = A.data.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
    Ai = A.indices.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int))
    Ap =      A.indptr.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int))
    eindptr = A.indptr.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int))
    eindptr_ = cast(pointer(eindptr), POINTER(c_void_p))
    eindptr_.contents.value += sizeof(eindptr._type_)

    C = np.zeros(m, dtype=np.float64)

    Bx = B.data.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
    Cx = C.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))

    alpha_beta = byref(c_double(1.))
    ldb_ldc = byref(c_int(0))
    no_transpose = byref(c_char(b'N'))
    general_matrix_c_order = c_char_p(b'G**C')

    #  mkl_dcscmm(transa, m, n, k,
    #             alpha, matdescra, val, indx, pntrb, pntre,
    #             b, ldb, beta, c, ldc)
    # docs: https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-mkl-cscmm
    ret = mkl.mkl_dcscmm(no_transpose, byref(c_int(m)), byref(c_int(Bn)), byref(c_int(n)),
                         alpha_beta, general_matrix_c_order, Ax, Ai, Ap, eindptr,
                         Bx, ldb_ldc, alpha_beta, Cx, ldb_ldc)

    return C


def test_csc_mm():
    np.random.seed(0)
    k = 10
    m, n = k, k

    A = csc_matrix(random(m, n, density=0.01)) + diags(np.ones(n))
    B = csc_matrix(random(m, n, density=0.01)) + diags(np.ones(n))

    t1 = time()
    C1 = A * B
    t_scipy = time() - t1
    print('time in scipy', t_scipy)

    t1 = time()
    C2 = sparse_csc_mm(A, B)
    t_mkl = time() - t1
    print('time in mkl',t_mkl)

    print('data in scipy', C1.data)
    print('data in mkl', C2)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test_csc_mm()
```

The console output is this:

> time in scipy 8.702278137207031e-05
>
> time in mkl 0.021214723587036133
>
> data in scipy [1.         0.96896177 1.         0.09609841 1.         1.   1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.        ]
>
> data in mkl [10.09609841 10.09609841  9.78273334 10.09609841  10.09609841 10.09609841   10.09609841 10.09609841 10.09609841 10.09609841]

Comment: It would be interesting to see the performance in the case if you will check the execution time only (around mkl_dcscmm() routine).  I expect that the initialization part of this example consumes most of the execution time.

Comment: The simplest check you can do is to change the matrices' size to 1000 for instance. Then the MKL routine takes about 20 seconds when the scipy takes one. Clearly there is something to do with the configuration, but the documentation is quite poor, hence the question.